# lazyload - preload adjacent images

Tags: javascript, jquery, preload, lazy-loading

I'm currently customizing a wordpess theme I bought which uses a lazyload function within its image galleries.

As it is now, the lazyload function only loads the visible image (which then gets cached). The adjacent images are hidden underneath and only will be loaded once made visible by clicking NEXT / PREVIOUS through the gallery.

This results is the sceen going blank for a second in between the images, which feels quite uncomfortable. Once the images are cached the whole NEXT / PREVIOUS process seems much more fluent.

Does anyone know if there a way to adjust the following lazyload code in a way, so it would preload not just the current, but also the next and previous image in advance?
Is that even possible within this part of the code?

I tried to find way by myself for a while now but couldn't resolve it...

Please excuse the horrible formatting, this is actually how the file was delivered with the theme. EDIT: Reformatted the code for better readability.

```
/*
 * Lazy Load - jQuery plugin for lazy loading images
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2012 Mika Tuupola
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Project home:
 *   http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload
 *
 * Version:  1.8.0
 *
 */
(function(a, b) {
    var c = a(b);
    a.fn.lazyload = function(d) {
        function h() {
            var b = 0;
            e.each(function() {
                var c = a(this);
                if (g.skip_invisible && !c.is(":visible")) return;
                if (!a.abovethetop(this, g) && !a.leftofbegin(this, g))
                    if (!a.belowthefold(this, g) && !a.rightoffold(this, g)) c.trigger("appear");
                    else if (++b > g.failure_limit) return !1
            })
        }
        var e = this,
            f, g = {
                threshold: 0,
                failure_limit: 0,
                event: "scroll",
                effect: "show",
                container: b,
                data_attribute: "original",
                skip_invisible: !0,
                appear: null,
                load: null
            };
        return d && (undefined !== d.failurelimit && (d.failure_limit = d.failurelimit, delete d.failurelimit), undefined !== d.effectspeed && (d.effect_speed = d.effectspeed, delete d.effectspeed), a.extend(g, d)), f = g.container === undefined || g.container === b ? c : a(g.container), 0 === g.event.indexOf("scroll") && f.bind(g.event, function(a) {
            return h()
        }), this.each(function() {
            var b = this,
                c = a(b);
            b.loaded = !1, c.one("appear", function() {
                if (!this.loaded) {
                    if (g.appear) {
                        var d = e.length;
                        g.appear.call(b, d, g)
                    }
                    a("<img />").bind("load", function() {
                        c.hide().attr("src", c.data(g.data_attribute))[g.effect](g.effect_speed), b.loaded = !0;
                        var d = a.grep(e, function(a) {
                            return !a.loaded
                        });
                        e = a(d);
                        if (g.load) {
                            var f = e.length;
                            g.load.call(b, f, g)
                        }
                    }).attr("src", c.data(g.data_attribute))
                }
            }), 0 !== g.event.indexOf("scroll") && c.bind(g.event, function(a) {
                b.loaded || c.trigger("appear")
            })
        }), c.bind("resize", function(a) {
            h()
        }), h(), this
    }, a.belowthefold = function(d, e) {
        var f;
        return e.container === undefined || e.container === b ? f = c.height() + c.scrollTop() : f = a(e.container).offset().top + a(e.container).height(), f <= a(d).offset().top - e.threshold
    }, a.rightoffold = function(d, e) {
        var f;
        return e.container === undefined || e.container === b ? f = c.width() + c.scrollLeft() : f = a(e.container).offset().left + a(e.container).width(), f <= a(d).offset().left - e.threshold
    }, a.abovethetop = function(d, e) {
        var f;
        return e.container === undefined || e.container === b ? f = c.scrollTop() : f = a(e.container).offset().top, f >= a(d).offset().top + e.threshold + a(d).height()
    }, a.leftofbegin = function(d, e) {
        var f;
        return e.container === undefined || e.container === b ? f = c.scrollLeft() : f = a(e.container).offset().left, f >= a(d).offset().left + e.threshold + a(d).width()
    }, a.inviewport = function(b, c) {
        return !a.rightofscreen(b, c) && !a.leftofscreen(b, c) && !a.belowthefold(b, c) && !a.abovethetop(b, c)
    }, a.extend(a.expr[":"], {
        "below-the-fold": function(b) {
            return a.belowthefold(b, {
                threshold: 0
            })
        },
        "above-the-top": function(b) {
            return !a.belowthefold(b, {
                threshold: 0
            })
        },
        "right-of-screen": function(b) {
            return a.rightoffold(b, {
                threshold: 0
            })
        },
        "left-of-screen": function(b) {
            return !a.rightoffold(b, {
                threshold: 0
            })
        },
        "in-viewport": function(b) {
            return !a.inviewport(b, {
                threshold: 0
            })
        },
        "above-the-fold": function(b) {
            return !a.belowthefold(b, {
                threshold: 0
            })
        },
        "right-of-fold": function(b) {
            return a.rightoffold(b, {
                threshold: 0
            })
        },
        "left-of-fold": function(b) {
            return !a.rightoffold(b, {
                threshold: 0
            })
        }
    })
})(jQuery, window)
```

Comment: Please, instead of adding a minified JavaScript of your source code, provide a well-formatted source code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to format it better and repost soon!
As said, it already came that awkward way...

Comment: We expect you to make an effort. Presenting somebody else's code and asking "How do I change this?" isn't sufficient. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I just unminified the code for better readability. I tried several thing to get a grip to this. First by myself using my humble JS skills, then getting in touch with the publisher of the theme (which declined and recommended getting a developer), then sitting down with a web designer friend of mine who is a bit more familiar with JS doing some considerable amount of research and trial and error approaches which led to no solution. Eventually we decided to post it here to ask for a direction.

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify libs. Instead trigger the lazyload event

Event to Trigger Loading
You can use **jQuery** event such as `click` or `mouseover`. You can also use custom events such as `sporty` or `foobar`. Default is to wait until user scrolls down and image appears on the viewport.

To load images only when user clicks them you could do:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
    event : "customloadimage" 
});
```

And then in your **jQuery** use `$image.trigger('customloadimage');`
(assuming `$image` is **jQuery** Object)

References:

https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Thanks a lot! We will try this!

Comment: @Apeiron First of all, I didn't down vote you. Second of all, there is no way to know who down voted you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)  (or a plugin that uses this API), you can take advantage of the "rootMargin" setting. By setting it to "800px" for example, it'll lazy-load the image 800px before it enters the viewport.